# Downloading a file with RTL characters in the name, with C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to download a file which has hebrew characters in the name

```
https://example.com/path/‏צילום מסך 2014‏.04‏.16 ב‏.16.44.30.png
```

When I try to download with the browser, the filename is correctly encoded and the server returns the file.

If I am downloading with C# code from the server, the filename is not encoded properly thus the server returns error 403.

If I encode the filename using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` and pass it to the `WebRequest` class, it is encoded properly but it has the same result (error 403).

I inspected the web calls with Fiddler and the encoded filename is different than what browser is encoding. If I get the filename and decode it, the filename is different (see below)

```
https://example.com/path/צילום מסך 2014.04.16 ב.16.44.30.png
```

I suspect that the problem is that the filename is partially encoded with Right-To-Left characters and the WebRequest class isn't equipped with the methods to handle it.
please see below the code used to download all of the files.

---

```
private byte[] GetFile(string url)
{
    byte[] result;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

    using (var remoteStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                count = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            } 
            while (count != 0);

            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Comment: What browser are you using (that the hebrew is correctly encoded in)?

Comment: Looks to me you are simply getting the day/month/year order wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant, I doubt this has anything to do with the date since the URL can be opened as it was originally in the question and there is no date modifications being done inside the code, only URL usage

Comment: Of course the hardest bugs to find are in the code you least suspect.

Comment: Works with all major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome). I don't have Safari installed.